# Livestream application in android

Tags: android, h.264, live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am working on Livestream application in android. I followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/) tutorial. But I am getting issue while encoding the video at surface view in micromax and lenovo mobiles. On other mobiles thats working fine. My exact requirement is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livestream.livestream&hl=en)

thanks for your values replays.